# Remove unidentified Bind variable in Toad popup window using oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, toad

I am trying to create a package in Oracle, whenever I try and execute it as a script, the following popup appears whereas I have not added any bind variable in my package code.

How can I identify where this popup is arising from in my package.

[image]

Comment: Do you have `&IBF` as part of a string literal within the package? Looks lie it's being picked up as a substitution variable rather than a normal bin variable.

Answer (score 1):

Did you **search** the package for `&IBF`? That should be your first move.

Then, as you use TOAD, open its **Options** and navigate to "Editor - Execute/Compile" section which contains the "Substitution variable prompting" whose options are:

- all
- ignore those in comments     --> I'd say this might be what you need to se
- none

Or, if you created the package in SQL*Plus, before running the `CREATE PACKAGE` command, `set define off`.

Comment: Yes, I tried searching for &IBF, but the issue was that in my comments I used '& IBF', due to space in between, I could not find it in search results.

Comment: Aha; OK, I'm glad you found it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that even if you write in a comment as "& IBF" in my case, Toad will ignore the space and consider it as a bind variable.

Make sure to search the string "IBF" instead of &IBF as in my case the editor did not return any results for "&IBF"

Comment: See [Enable/Disable prompt for Substitution Variables](https://support.quest.com/toad-for-oracle/kb/11560/no-prompt-for-substitution-variable-how-do-you-enable-disable-prompt-for-variable-substitution) in TOAD.